# Prevent Swiper Slide move on click event

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, swiper.js

I am using Swiper JS (https://swiperjs.com/vue). Each swiper slide contains a button. When clicking on the slide or the button, the slide becomes the active slide, causing the slider to move.

Can I prevent the slider from moving when clicking the button of an inactive slide?

I've tried setting `preventClicks` to `true`, but unfortunately it didn't work.

It can be replicated here (https://swiperjs.com/demos/110-slides-per-view/core.html) by clicking on inactive slides. I've noticed some clicks don't move the slider, others do.

```
<swiper :modules="modules"
            :scrollbar="{ draggable: true }"
            :navigation="{prevEl: '#prev-slide', nextEl: '#next-slide', disabledClass: 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none'}"
            :breakpoints="options.breakpoints"
    >
        <swiper-slide v-for="plan in plans" :key="plan.id">
            <plan :plan="plan" @set-plan="setPlan"/>
        </swiper-slide>

        <div class="flex justify-center mt-2 space-x-2 py-3">
            <button type="button"
                    id="prev-slide"
                    class="inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-1.5 border border-gray-300 shadow-sm text-xs font-medium rounded text-gray-700 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500">
                <arrow-narrow-left-icon class="h-5 w-5"/>
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                    id="next-slide"
                    class="inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-1.5 border border-gray-300 shadow-sm text-xs font-medium rounded text-gray-700 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500">
                <arrow-narrow-right-icon class="h-5 w-5"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </swiper>
```

Comment: Your swiper slides because you move your mouse a little bit when you click, not because you click.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden, you are wrong. I had the same problem, on a slider where i had a button. At the first click, the slide changed. I solved it by disabling/removing a11y.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden lol thanks for this comment, our QA person who clicks like a madwoman reported this bug and you are right, that is the reason

Answer (score 3):

> When we click on any link or button, the swiper slide of that button gets active and we see it sliding. This usually happens when we have slidesPerView:'auto'.
> To prevent this , there is an attribute 'a11y', set to false as:

```
   {
   slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 25,
    freeMode: true,
    preventClicks :true,
    a11y: false,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The desired functionality can be achieved using the prop `noSwipingSelector` with a value of `button`. When clicking the button of an inactive slide, it no longer swipes to the active slide.

Answer (score 1):

It slides because of focusing on a button.
I resolved it by disabling a11y on the certain slider.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me, but I found a solution in the docs:

noSwipingSelector: 'a',

Makes it so links are clickable again, and swiping on a link in the slide doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

We have a new field for it.

Use:

```
watchSlidesProgress: true,
```